# How to implement a matrix multiplication in Keras?

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I just want to implement a function that given a matrix X returns the covariance matrix of X (X^T*X), which is just a simple matrix multiplication.

In Tensorflow it's gonna be easy: tf.matmul(X, tf.transpose(X))

But I didn't expect that it's a nightmare with Keras. The APIs in Keras like multiply and dot don't fit my request. I also tried different ways (Lambda layer and mixed with TF operations) but still failed, occurred lots of errors.

Hope someone may help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you do have the analogous in Keras. Try `dot(x, transpose(x))`.

A working example comparing the two platforms follows.

```py
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def cov_tf(x_val):
    x = tf.constant(x_val)
    cov = tf.matmul(x, tf.transpose(x))
    return cov.eval(session=tf.Session())

def cov_keras(x_val):
    x = K.constant(x_val)
    cov = K.dot(x, K.transpose(x))
    return cov.eval(session=tf.Session())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.random.rand(4, 5)
    delta = np.abs(cov_tf(x) - cov_keras(x)).max()
    print('Maximum absolute difference:', delta)
```

The maximum absolute difference is printed and gives me something around `1e-7`.

Comment: If the goal is to perform a matrix product as a layer of a model then you should not use the backend. keras.backend will just refer the operation to the backend framework, and that causes problems when saving the model.
Instead you should use keras.layers.dot which is specifically for performing tensor products in a model layer. https://keras.io/layers/merge/#dot

Comment: Hi, @grovina, I'm a newbie to TensorFlow. I'm curious about the backend setting above. You have imported the TensorFlow explicitly. Then why do you need to ```import keras.backend as K``` at the same time?

Comment: @Jie, note that TF and Keras merged so you don't need to think of them separately. You could probably do it the Keras way natively in TF.

Answer (score 2):

You must have a layer, and inside the layer make the calculation.

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda
from keras.models import Model

inp = Input((your input shape))
previousLayerOutput = SomeLayerBeforeTheCovariance(blabla)(inp)    

covar = Lambda(lambda x: K.dot(K.transpose(x),x), 
    output_shape = (your known shape of x))(previousLayerOutput)

nextOut = SomeOtherLayerAfterThat(blablabla)(covar)
lastOut = AnotherLayer(bahblanba)(nextOut)

model = Model(inp, lastOut)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Still hate to use Lambda, but you are absolutely correct ---> "You must have a layer" for your output to be useful in a model.

Comment: Yes, but the solution you suggest will not save to file, ie you will not be able to serialize the model with keras.Model.save. Though keras.Model.save_weights will probably work if you don't need to save the whole model.
Use keras.layers.dot instead of making a lamda layer with a backend product.
https://keras.io/layers/merge/#dot

Comment: It does save and load.

Comment: But today I would recommend `tf.matmul`, it's so much easier to understand how it works.

Answer (score -1):

You can use keras.layers.merge.Multiply()

It takes as input a list of tensors, all of the same shape, and returns a single tensor (also of the same shape).

[The keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/merge/)

Cheers A.

Comment: This is elementwise multiplication, not matrix multiplication.

Comment: I think keras.layers.Dot() does a dot product / matrix multiplication